# mysqli_real_escape_string and double quotes issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['var']);
$sql = "UPDATE users SET var = '$var' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

If the var is `aaa`, it's ok, even if the var is `aa'bbb`, but if the var is `sss"ddd` - the var that updated is just `sss`.
I know it's because the mysql query contains `"`.

Any idea?

Comment: Try to debug `$sql` (with var_dump if need be) and show us what's in there.

Comment: "UPDATE users SET var = 'abc\"def' WHERE id = '457'"

Comment: You should use prpared statements to avoud sql injection. Also the escaping of special charater will be done by value binding.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Maybe magic quotes is still on..

Answer (score 1):

Before starting with PHP you have to learn HTML basics first.
Also, you have to understand the difference between two.

So, don't blame PHP for your incomplete HTML.
Open page source and see your `sss"ddd` sound and safe, however spoiling HTML like this

```
<input value="sss"ddd">
```

and from now on pass every form value through `htmlspecialchars()`