# MySQLI real_escape_string not allowing strings with double quotes to be stored

Tags: php, mysqli

this is my first post here but I've heavily used this site for many years. The people here are great.

For some reason, the MySQLI real_escape_string is throwing out any string that has a double quote in it.

For instance, this will be stored into the DB without a problem:

```
Wayne's Group Name
```

But this can't be:

```
"Wayne's Group Name"
```

And looking further into it, just a lone double quote is not stored either.

Here's how I'm doing the escaping right now:

```
 $Group1Name = $link->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Group1Name']);
```

But nothing ever gets through to the variable if there is a double quote.

I'm stumped.

PHP version: 5.6.19

Apache version: Apache/2.4.18 (Fedora)

MariaDB version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.23-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Here is the page where I'm having this issue.
https://github.com/wayneworkman/jane/blob/master/janeADPostProcessing.php

Comment: I'd just remove the `real_escape_string` calls alltogether. Just make sure you don't add the variables directly to the query (use placeholders).

Comment: I used `addslashes` function to escape quotes, double quotes and backslashes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672007/mysqli-real-escape-string-and-double-quotes-issue Same problem?

Comment: Can we see your query?

Comment: Just use prepared statements to make things easier for you.

Comment: @Matt I linked to the source code of my project where the above snippet came from. The MySQL queries are in there at the bottom.

Comment: There is not a single issue with real escape string and quotes. The problem is in your code. You have to debug it to hunt it down.

Comment: I figured it out, the values with double quotes are being stored, the issue was the HTML formatting when displaying the data at a later time.